# NEON: How to convert an 128 bit ARGB to 32 bit ARGB with saturation?

Tags: assembly, arm, neon

I have an ARGB pixel stored in an 128 bit NEON register as 32bit per channel. I need to store this into memory as an 8bit channel ARGB (narrowing and saturating).

I got my result after a vmla.32 q1, q2, d0; wondering if I could achieve narrowing or saturation through the mul instruction directly saving some cycles.

What's the best way to go about it?

Comment: are your color components unsigned, or can the 32 bit component become negative (e.g. saturation to zero required as well)?

Answer (score 1):

There's no such encoding as `vmla.32 q1, q2, d0`; let's assume you meant `q0`.

The simple, naive answer is:

```
vqmovn.s32  d0, q1  // saturate and narrow 32 -> 16
vqmovn.s16  d0, q0  // saturate and narrow 16 -> 8
```

this does signed saturation; if you have unsigned values, use the `.u32` and `.u16` types, and if you have signed values but want to saturate to unsigned, you use the `vqmovun` instruction.

To your question of whether or not you can do some sort of narrowing multiply, that depends heavily on the exact operation (and the values involved); given that you're using a `vmla`, the answer is "probably not", however.

Can you use the saturating operations in NEON and avoid widening to start with, or do you need all of that headroom?